# Looking for old C compiler

Tags: development, classic-mac-os

Back in 1987 or 1988 we had a Mac network at college, these would have been either Mac Classic or Mac Plus machines. We used a C compiler on them - what C compilers were around at the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be [Think C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THINK_C) or Apple's [Macintosh Programmers' Workshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) Note links are to Wikipedia, which is probably OK for information for old computing.

Comment: Think C was the definitive C compiler, until CodeWarrior came out in the early 90's. The original Mac OS and applications were written in a combination of Pascal and 68K assembly.

Answer (score 2):

There was also the [Consulair Mac C Development System](http://macintoshgarden.org/apps/consulair-mac-c-development-system).